# Screen not created for drawstring text to display

Tags: java

I am working on Java Game Development Tutorials given on buckysroom.org. I am creating a Screen class, which allows me to go full screen. Then, when I try to paint it with text, the screen does not appear, and only the text is shown on my working window (Eclipse) If I comment out the paint method or make it paintComponent, the red screen appears, but without any text. Can anyone help me on how to deal with this?

The Screen class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Screen {

private GraphicsDevice vc;

public Screen() {
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    vc = env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
}

public void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window) {
    window.setUndecorated(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(window);
    if (dm != null && vc.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
        try {
            vc.setDisplayMode(dm);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}

public Window getFullScreenWindow() {
    return vc.getFullScreenWindow();
}

public void restoreScreen() {
    Window w = vc.getFullScreenWindow();
    if (w != null) {
        w.dispose();
    }
    vc.setFullScreenWindow(null);
 }
}
```

This is the class where I call it:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class bucky extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    bucky m = new bucky();
    m.run(dm);
}

public void run(DisplayMode dm) {
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
    setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
    Screen s = new Screen();
    try {
        s.setFullScreen(dm, this);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    } finally {
        s.restoreScreen();
    }    
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.drawString("This is awesome", 200, 200);
 }
}
```

Comment: I would suspect two things, 1- `Thread.sleep` is causing the EDT to sleep thus never calling `paint` and 2- `paint` is not the best choice for this operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suspicion is that the `Thread.sleep` is cause the Event Dispatching Thread to be put to sleep, preventing it from processing any paint events (or any other kind of events for that matter) and/or the `paint` method of the `JFrame` is not an appropriate method for performing paint in (generally it's not for a number of reasons)...

Instead, you should consider using something like `javax.swing.Timer` which you can use to set up an alarm for some time in the future and it will call you back.

You should also consider using something like a `JPanel` to perform your custom painting on, for example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class FullScreenTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FullScreenTest();
    }

    public FullScreenTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setContentPane(new TestPane());

                DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800, 600, 16, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
                Screen.setFullScreen(null, frame);

                Timer timer = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Screen.restoreScreen();
                    }
                });
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24));
            setBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g.drawString("This is awesome", 200, 200);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

    public static class Screen {

        public static GraphicsDevice getGraphicsDevice() {
            GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            return env.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        }

        public static void setFullScreen(DisplayMode dm, JFrame window) {
            window.setUndecorated(true);
            window.setResizable(false);
            GraphicsDevice gd = getGraphicsDevice();
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(window);
            if (dm != null && gd.isDisplayChangeSupported()) {
                try {
                    gd.setDisplayMode(dm);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        }

        public static Window getFullScreenWindow() {
            GraphicsDevice gd = getGraphicsDevice();
            return gd.getFullScreenWindow();
        }

        public static void restoreScreen() {
            GraphicsDevice gd = getGraphicsDevice();
            Window w = gd.getFullScreenWindow();
            if (w != null) {
                w.dispose();
            }
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(null);
        }
    }

}
```

Take a look at:

- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

For more details...

Also, because of the type of work it's doing, `Screen` could also be a fully `static` class.  It maintains no contextual information and simply provides utility functionality - IMHO.

If you needed one for each `GraphicsDevice`, that would be another story ;)